# Is there a better method of creating a list of quarters by counting back from a given quarter?

Tags: javascript

I have done this function which creates an array of quarters, counting back x quarters including from specified quarter.

The last item in the array is the reference quarter.

For example, with reference quarter `2` and a count of `9`, this would yield `[2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]`;

My function works, but I would like to know, if there is a simpler, more elegant solution to this.

**Code below:**

```js
/// Counts back x from specified quarter
/// Parameters:
/// @param countFrom   -- the reference quarter to count back from
/// @param count       -- count
///
/// @returns array     -- the array of quarters
function getQuarterList(countFrom, count) {
 var ret = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){
  var z = countFrom - i;
  while (z < 1) {
   z = z + 4;
  }
  ret.splice(0, 0, z);
 }

 return ret;
}

var quarterList = getQuarterList(2, 9);
console.log(quarterList);
```

Comment: At least use `unshift` instead of `splice` if you want to do it that way.

Comment: If you don't mind a little code-golf, this works where `countFrom` is 1, 2, 3, or 4: `let q=(s,t)=>Array(t+s).fill(0).map((c,i)=>i%4+1).splice(s-1,t)`

Comment: I ended up upvoting all the answers, because they are all good solutions. Reason for why I chose the accepted answer: The way how it is implemented is **simple enough**, **readable**, and ***provides control*** through a callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the start value

```js
function getQuarterList(countFrom, count) {
    var offset = (countFrom - count) % 4 + 4;
    return Array.apply(null, { length: count }).map(function (_, i) {
        return (i + offset) % 4 + 1;
    });
}

console.log(getQuarterList(2, 9));
console.log(getQuarterList(3, 7));
console.log(getQuarterList(1, 2));
console.log(getQuarterList(4, 9));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage on the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function and on the arithmetical module operator. Here follow a generalized version of your function:

```
function getModuleList(countFrom, count, mod) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    arr.push(i + countFrom);
  }

  return arr.map(function(num){ return num % mod || mod });

}

var quarterList = getModuleList(2, 9, 4);
console.log(quarterList);
```

Comment: Good generic solution, could be used for months/weeks as well.

Answer (score 1):

That `while` loop can be omitted if you just use `countFrom` as the counter:

```
function getQuarterList(countFrom, count) {
    // assert: countFrom ∈ [1..4]
    var ret = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ret.unshift(countFrom)
        countFrom--;
        if (countFrom < 1)
            countFrom += 4;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

An easier approach would be to compute which value to start at and use the module operator:

```
function getQuarterList(countFrom, count) {
    var ret = [];
    var z = (countFrom - count % 4 + 4) % 4;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ret.push(++z)
        z %= 4;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this job as follows;

```js
var quarters = (n,m) => Array(...Array(m - m%4 + n%4)).map((e,i) => i%4 + 1)
                                                      .slice(this.length-m);
console.log(quarters(2,9));
```

Well thinking further i believe i can not get any more functional than this.

```js
var quarters = (n,m) => Array(...Array(m)).map((e,i) => (Math.abs(m%4-n) + i)%4 + 1);
console.log(quarters(1,11));
console.log(quarters(3,7));
console.log(quarters(2,9));
```